# Returning value from array

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have Inventories table and here I save all ProductId's who is below 10 or the same as 10 in Array

```
public int[] OrderNow()
{
    return context.Inventory.Where(u => u.Quantity <= 10).Select(i =>i.ProductId)
                                                         .ToArray();
}
```

I know I have 3 products that Quantity is below 10 and when I run debug I can see those Ids. So far so good.

But When I want to retrieve names of those products, I just can get one of those 3 products...

To get names of those Products I wrote this code, but it's returning only one Product name.

```
public string[] ProductName()
{
     var prId = OrderNow();
     foreach (var p in prId)
     {

       return context.Products.Where(u => u.ProductId == p)
                              .Select(p => p.ProductName).ToArray();
          // After one loop it's jumping foreach process .. I don't know why
     }
     return null; // I don't know what to write here, but I must to return something
}
```

Edited with a similar problem...

```
public int[] OrderNow()
{
    return context.Inventory.Where(u => u.Quantity <= 10).Select(i =>i.DepartmentId)
                                                         .ToArray();
}
```

And my User email

```
public string[] UserEmails()
{
   var departmentIds= OrderNow();   // Gets the array of product ids

   return context.Users
         .Where(u => u.IsInventoryAdmin == true)
                 .Where(u => departmentIds.Contains(u.DepartmentId)) // Here failing
                 .Select(e => e.Email)
                 .ToArray();    
}
```

Comment: `return` breaks out of a method.

Comment: `return` exits your function. And you are already returning `string[]`

Comment: @DanielA.White thank you for your response, What Should I write instead?

Comment: Best guess is you want just `return context.Products.Where(u => prId.Contains(u.ProductId)).Select(p => p.ProductName).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are returning inside the loop. So when the loop executes for the first item in the `prId` array, it gets only that product (*Basically a collection with only that product*) and since you have the `return` statement, it will be returned(exiting that code block).Your loop iteration will not be executed for the remaining items in the array.

You should use `Contains` method. This allows you to query the Products which has ProductId matching to items inside the array ( the productIds you got from OrderNow method)

```
public string[] ProductName()
{
   var productIds= OrderNow();   // Gets the array of product ids

   return context.Products
                 .Where(u => productIds.Contains(u.ProductId))
                 .Select(p => p.ProductName)
                 .ToArray();    
}
```

Comment: Yea. Just fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @Shyju I get Error when I want to do allmost like you answered. This time  I collected departmentId in Array from OrderNow() Then in my Asp.NetUsers I have departmentId, and emails. I wanted to collect ueser emails in Array who have the same departmentId. Its allmost the same if you change Products to Users in you answer. I get error int[] does not contain for definition for 'Contains' and the best extenstion method overload 'Queryable.Contains<int?> .....'

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` to that class file.

Comment: @Shyju I have edited my original question in the bottom

Comment: try `.Where(u => departmentIds.Any(u.DepartmentId))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155668/discussion-between-helen-tekie-and-shyju).

Comment: @Shyju now error Changes to =>  cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Func<int, bool>'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155693/discussion-between-helen-tekie-and-shyju).